# How to get all categories for a specific product in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have next query

```
db.test_products.find(
{ $text: { $search: 'Iphone 6' } },
{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
.sort({ score:{$meta: "textScore",  } })
.limit(20)
```

It gives me first 20 products, but we have more than 20 results and I would like to have **all** the categories for a searched term, so next on UI we will be able to show all the categories for our searched product

Expected output should look like this

```
{
    products: [{1...20}],
    categories: [
        "Mobile Phones",
        "Cellphones & Telecommunications/Phone Bags & Cases/Wallet Cases",
        "Cellphones & Telecommunications/Mobile Phone Parts/Mobile Phone Motherboards",
        "Cellphones & Telecommunications/Mobile Phone Parts/Mobile Phone LCD Screens",
        "...",
    ]
}
```

It should be possible to write such query in Mongo for sure, but I can not figure it out how to do it now

Note: I have a **text** index now for a 'title' and not sure if there will be a big difference if we will decide to use **search** index with realm to implement autocomplete

Would be grateful for any help!

[dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XFYZB9SMf2o-h4FD2M7VKoyd2ccwW1GD/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` to get the unique set of all categories for a given query

```
db.test_products.distinct("category", { $text: { $search: 'Iphone 6' } })
```

Comment: Thank you Zack! Is it possible to get products and distinct categories in 1 query or it must be 2 queries? Like one to get the products an then to get categories it belongs to?

Comment: I dont think you can (I mean, technically anything is possible, but it would require a really gnarly aggregation) and also I can't imagine why you'd want to - to get the list of all categories, you need to look at all every unique value. With an index on `category` this will be very fast. To get the search results you're already using the text index, and only looking at 20 documents. If you mixed them, I think you'd end up with a substantially slower result